# Facebook & iOS Login Bug since January 2012 - Even with ShareKit or SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

Since the last week in January we've seen most of our iOS apps, and those commercially available on the app store have problems logging in and posting to Facebook. We've also seen this with apps using ShareKit to post to FB.

I've filed bugs with FB and got nowhere other than that people confirm they are seeing the same thing.

Today I did some NSLog's of the URL requests and redirect URLs where the problem is showing itself...

Could someone please try and help?

BTW - Please note - all of this was working perfectly before Jan 26th 2012. There has been no code changes on our side since then.

**So we have an empty UIWebView and we make the login request**

2012-02-22 12:32:28.870 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=135916249814649&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_stream,user_photos&type=user_agent&display=touch>

2012-02-22 12:32:32.531 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=135916249814649&display=touch&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_photos&fbconnect=1>

2012-02-22 12:32:35.671 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=135916249814649&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D135916249814649%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%252Cuser_photos%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D135916249814649&rcount=1&_rdr>
[Switching to process 1640 thread 0x15203]

**At this point the FB login page is shown inside the iOS UIWebView. After correctly entering in a valid FB email address and password, the following occurs.**

2012-02-22 12:32:56.632 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = https://m.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D135916249814649%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%252Cuser_photos%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D135916249814649&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9>

2012-02-22 12:32:59.547 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = https://m.facebook.com/#!/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=135916249814649&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_photos&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=135916249814649&refid=9>

2012-02-22 12:33:02.034 iPad App[1640:15203] REQUEST = https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=135916249814649&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_photos&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=135916249814649&refid=9>

**And here's the error that the UIWebView returns. Note - all this happens BEFORE the UIWebView is dismissed and BEFORE we even sent the POST to FB url.**

2012-02-22 12:33:02.035 iPad App[1640:15203] ERROR = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x8a136d0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://m.facebook.com/#!/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=135916249814649&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_photos&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=135916249814649&refid=9, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://m.facebook.com/#!/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=135916249814649&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_photos&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=135916249814649&refid=9}

=========

So, other than "FB is broke..." which they don't seem to be doing anything about nor addressing this issue as it's been almost a month and we have shouting and complaining customers and users... what else could be going on?

Some apps (our own and 3rd party) that use share kit are working, and some not...

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not being facetious, but have you tried asking Facbook?

Comment: As I said in the post, yes I have and I've had no response. I've seen that this 'bug' was originally reported in Oct 2011 and was closed, but people are still posting on the closed bug as of the end of january to say it's still happening.

Comment: A bug is a bug. Your dialog should happen with Facebook. What can we do here on StackOverflow for you, we're all just 3rd party developers just like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

FB changed not only some URL's but changed the way the Client Side Authentication worked and didn't bother to tell anyone.

If you look at the Javascript code for Client Side Authentication and emulate this in iOS it works fine.

(for the moment.)

Gods I hate Facebook so much...